# .Net Core - How to publish a solution with n-layers

Tags: .net, .net-core

Currently i finished to make a solution with multiple layers

1. Service-App (Web application)
2. Business-Layer (Class Collection)
3. Data-Access (Class Collection)

Service-App has dependencies of Business-layer and Data-Access

I wanna publish the solution in a specified folder, im trying to do this command but i got some issues

```
dotnet publish -c release -r win-x64 --output ./[OutputFolder]
```

**My question is if i need to execute this command in the solution folder or maybe in the Service-App folder**

Comment: You have written "i got some issues" what are the issues? In my optinion executing this in project folder should work fine because the "startup" project (Web app?) should have the references to the other libraries and will include them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you reference other layers into the main web application you don't need to write different code
and you should execute in on solution folder
but if you need to add anything else these are the parameters in the dotnet core CLI

```
dotnet publish [<PROJECT>|<SOLUTION>] [-c|--configuration <CONFIGURATION>]
[-f|--framework <FRAMEWORK>] [--force] [--interactive]
[--manifest <PATH_TO_MANIFEST_FILE>] [--no-build] [--no-dependencies]
[--no-restore] [--nologo] [-o|--output <OUTPUT_DIRECTORY>]
[-p:PublishReadyToRun=true] [-p:PublishSingleFile=true] [-p:PublishTrimmed=true]
[-r|--runtime <RUNTIME_IDENTIFIER>] [--self-contained [true|false]]
[--no-self-contained] [-v|--verbosity <LEVEL>]
[--version-suffix <VERSION_SUFFIX>]
```